# Highlight navigation link as i scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple page like the code below

```
<nav>
    <a  href="#menu1">menu1</a>
    <a  href="#menu2">menu2</a>
    <a  href="#menu3">menu3</a>
    <a  href="#menu4">menu4 </a>
</nav>


<section id="menu1"></section>      
<section id="menu2"></section>          
<section id="menu3"></section>          
<section id="menu4"></section>
```

How can I highlight each navigation link when I change the section, as I scroll down the page?

Is it possible to be done using css?

Here is an example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYw35/1/)

I need the grey background color to change when i change section...

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034555/how-to-make-side-id-navigation-links-active-hover-state-as-i-scroll-down-to-thei?rq=1

Comment: With your HTML structure it looks like you would like to use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: `$('section').mouseenter(function() { $('nav a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active').siblings('nav a').removeClass('active'); });` - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zkrh7/)

Comment: @mdesdev add it as answer, its a rather cool solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concept broken down:

Get at what height each div is and assign it to a variable
if first.y > current -> show first 
if first.y < current < second -> show second etc etc

here is some code to illustrate the example

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    var div_one_top = $('#one').position().top;
    var div_two_top = $('#two').position().top;

    if(scroll_top > div_one_top && scroll_top < div_two_top) {
        //You are now past div one
        $('#sidebar').text('One');
    } else if( scroll_top > div_two_top) {
        //You are now past div two
       $('#sidebar').text('Two');
    }
});
```

in your case a switch(y pos) might be better

Answer (score 1):

Not on scroll but solid solution, detects `mouseenter` and by that assigning active class to links.

```
$('section').mouseenter(function() {
  $('nav a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active').siblings('nav a').removeClass('active');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zkrh7/)**

**Update:** Here's on scroll solution

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $('nav a[href="#'+$('section:hover').attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active').siblings('nav a').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: can you please update a your fiddle with your scroll solution?

Comment: I've update the fiddle with scroll solution when I posted update. Just uncomment code for scroll in the fiddle.

Comment: It's working just fine, I don't know what are you talking about.

Answer (score 0):

A little javascript can do this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
})
</script>
```

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/nYw35/3/)

**[UPDATED]**

Just add the ids in every links:

```
    <nav>
        <a id="a" href="#menu1" class="active">menu1</a>
        <a id="b" href="#menu2">menu2</a>
        <a id="c" href="#menu3">menu3</a> 
        <a id="d" href="#menu4">menu4 </a>
    </nav>
```

How about that if you store the clicked element `a#id` and then add the class when page is being scroll.
Check this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/nYw35/11/)

Here is the updated code -

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var id;
    $(document).on('click','a',function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
    }).scroll(function(){
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $("#"+id).addClass('active');        
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Cool but is it possible to change as i scroll down the page(I mean without clicking)?

Comment: @Mitsos - Please check my updated answer may be this can work as your expectation.

Comment: You are giving class active to section on scroll.

Comment: @mdesdev - Yes thats what OP is looking for. i think you should read his comment. `is it possible to change as i scroll down the page(I mean without clicking)?`

Comment: Question is "Highlight **navigation link** as i scroll down the page" not "Highlight **section** as i scroll down the page" and you're giving class `active` to section on scroll.

Comment: I think i did not updated my complete answer.. actually i have added ids in every links. and i am adding active class in anchors with its ID not section. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Ok you've updated the answer but still what are you doing on scroll `$("#"+id).addClass('active');` what `id`. Id of the clicked element, ok, but what about changing active class accordingly with active section.

Answer (score 0):

Partly working solution to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/nYw35/4/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    var one_top = $('#menu1').position().top;
    var two_top = $('#menu2').position().top;

    if (scroll_top > one_top && scroll_top < two_top) {
        $('a[href="#menu1"]').removeClass('active');
        $('a[href="#menu2"]').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give unique id to all menu link.
Call one function on click event of all that link and pass that id using this attribute to that function
and add active class by using for link of that respective link using that id.