# Highlighting the sidebar links with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side bar for a settings page which is like an index. I want the appropriate links to highlight every time I scroll to a different section of the page. I realize this has been asked before, and I tried doing what was told in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887258/highlight-navigation-link-as-i-scroll-down-the-page) . I also looked at a couple of blogs, though their code seems quite complicated.

HTML

```
        <div id="sidebar">

              <nav class="navlinks">
                    <ul style="list-style:none" id="sidebar-id">

                             <li> <a href="#Profile-settings"> Profile </a></li>
                             <li> <a href="#social-settings"> Social Media </a></li>
                             <li> <a href="#"> Logout </a></li>

                      /ul>
                  </nav>       
             </div>

<section id="Profile-settings">
    <!--some content-->
    </section>

         <section id="social-settings">
    <!--some content-->
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    color:red;    
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
        var div_one_top = $('#Profile-settings').position().top;
        var div_two_top = $('#social-settings').position().top;

        if(scroll_top > div_one_top && scroll_top < div_two_top) {
            //You are now past div one
            $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').addClass('active');
            $('a[href="#social-settings"]').removeClass('active');
        } else if (scroll_top > div_two_top) {
            $('a[href="#social-settings"]').addClass('active');
            $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').removeClass('active');


        }
    });

    });
```

When I run this though, only the `<li> <a href="#Profile-settings">Profile</a></li>` shows the active class, constantly, meaning it wont change when I scroll to the bottom or top. The second `li`(#social settings) wont have the `.highlight` class get added to it at all. 
I'm very new to javascript and jquery, and am grateful for all the help. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Try `$(window).scroll` instead of `$(document).scroll`? (Also `$(window).scrollTop()`) `$('#Profile-settings').offset().top` instead of `position()`

Comment: It didn't work Av Avt

Comment: Please check my answer. There are many minor things that must be done so I can't write them all in a comment. If something's too confusing just tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed `<` for `</ul>`.When I add this `<` to `/ul>`,everything is well in my browser.

Adding 

`console.log(div_one_top,div_two_top);
console.log(scroll_top);`

before `if`statement,you can check the data from console.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's a problem. That was a type when I copy-pasted the code from my editor, but thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Since the position of these elements on the
```

page are not changing and you don't want to recalculate them every time the page scrolls it 
would be more efficient to move them out of the 
scroll function.
    */

```
var div_one_top = $('#Profile-settings').position().top;
var div_two_top = $('#social-settings').position().top;

/* You need to grab the body tag and wrap 
     it in parentheses. */
    $('body').scroll(function () {
        /* you can use this since the body is the
         context element that you are passing in. */
        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(scroll_top > div_one_top && scroll_top < div_two_top) {
            //You are now past div one
            $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').addClass('active');
            $('a[href="#social-settings"]').removeClass('active');
        } else if (scroll_top > div_two_top) {
            $('a[href="#social-settings"]').addClass('active');
            $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').removeClass('active');


        }
    });

    });
```

Comment: It didn't help andre, I don't know where I'm going wrongs. The logic does seem right to me

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, the added css is only for demo, only the js part matters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_one_top = $('#Profile-settings').offset().top;
    var div_two_top = $('#social-settings').offset().top;

    if (scroll_top > div_one_top && scroll_top < div_two_top) {
      //You are now past div one
      if (!$('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').hasClass('active')) {
        $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').addClass('active');
      }

      if ($('a[href="#social-settings"]').hasClass('active')) {
        $('a[href="#social-settings"]').removeClass('active');
      }

    } else if (scroll_top > div_two_top) {
      if ($('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').hasClass('active')) {
        $('a[href="#Profile-settings"]').removeClass('active');
      }

      if (!$('a[href="#social-settings"]').hasClass('active')) {
        $('a[href="#social-settings"]').addClass('active');

      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

section{
  min-height: 110vh;
}

#sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#sidebar li{
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar li a{
  color: white;
}

#sidebar li a.active {
  color: red;
}

#Profile-settings{
  background-color: blue;
}
#social-settings{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">

  <nav class="navlinks">
    <ul style="list-style:none" id="sidebar-id">

      <li> <a href="#Profile-settings"> Profile </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#social-settings"> Social Media </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Logout </a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section id="Profile-settings">
  Profile section
</section>

<section id="social-settings">
  Social section
</section>
```